# How to Increment the first element in a row if the second element is equal to desired number in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Suppose I have a 2D Numpy array with a structure that looks something like this:

```py
my_list = np.array( [[a,b],
                     [c,d],
                     [e,f],
                    ...  ] )
```

Now consider a list of inputs like `[1,2,3,4,5]`. I want to match every first element of *my_list* (elements of the first column) with the input list and increment the second element of my_list where a match happens.

How can I achieve this using NumPy functions?
I've tried `map( lambda x: np.add(my_list[:,1] , 1 , where = (my_list[:,0] == x) ) , inp_list)` but this gives me some bizarre result which is no where near what I want.

Let's give you an example.

```
my_list = np.array( [[1,100],
                     [2,120],
                     [3,150],
                     [4,190],
                     [5,98],])
input_list = [1,4,5]
```

Consider the snippet above as inputs. Now I'm looking for output like this:

```
my_output = np.array( [[1,101],
                       [2,120],
                       [3,150],
                       [4,191],
                       [5,99],])
```

Basically, the second column of every row which matches the input_list has been incremented by one.

Comment: Can you show sample input and output?

Comment: Sure, I added an example to the question.

Comment: Are the values in the 1st column of `my_list` always sequential?

Comment: No, not always.

Comment: Are values all unique in `input_list`?

Comment: Yes, they are all unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.isin` to check if the values are in a list or not, then use `np.where` to get the values, i.e. `value+1` if in list, else just the value, and assign it back to the slice:

```py
my_list[:,1] = np.where(np.isin(my_list[:,0],input_list), my_list[:,1]+1, my_list[:,1])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
array([[  1, 101],
       [  2, 120],
       [  3, 150],
       [  4, 191],
       [  5,  99]])
```

Answer (score 1):

One very straightforward way is to convert the array `my_list` to a *dict*, a sort of counter, then update it with the keys in `input_list`:

```
>>> d = dict(my_list)
{1: 100, 2: 120, 3: 150, 4: 190, 5: 98}
```

Update the *dict* `d`:

```
>>> for x in input_list:
...   d[x] += 1
```

Then convert back to an *ndarray*:

```
>>> np.stack(list(d.items()))
array([[  1, 101],
       [  2, 120],
       [  3, 150],
       [  4, 191],
       [  5,  99]])
```

Comment: Interestingly I used the same method to calculate it the first time I coded it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_list = np.array([[1,100],
                    [2,120],
                    [3,150],
                    [4,190],
                    [5,98]])

input_list = np.array([1,4,5])

my_list[:,1] += np.logical_or.reduce(my_list[:,0,None] == input_list, axis=1)

my_list
```

Output:

```
array([[  1, 101],
       [  2, 120],
       [  3, 150],
       [  4, 191],
       [  5,  99]])
```

Timings:

```
%timeit my_list[:,1] = np.where(np.isin(my_list[:,0],input_list), my_list[:,1]+1, my_list[:,1])
14.6 µs ± 199 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit my_list[:,1] += np.logical_or.reduce(my_list[:,0,None] == input_list, axis=1)
4.94 µs ± 23.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```